# Why doesn't a question I asked show up on my home page?

Tags: support

A few months ago I asked this question

[Why is there a dagesh in second camocha, but not in first?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47615/why-is-there-a-dagesh-in-second-camocha-but-not-in-first)

and got a nice answer and a bunch of people also liked the question.  So why does my home page show no questions?

Answer (score 2):

You posted that question from a different account. If you want to merge the two accounts, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/contact